# converting resnet-50 network based on tensorflow with TensorRT3.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorrt

see this problem

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 489, in import_graph_def
>   graph._c_graph, serialized, options) # pylint: disable=protected-access
>   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 4 for 'import/dense_p7/MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [1,256,1,1], [256,1]

we can successfully complete the tensorrt subgraph convension, but we meet the problem during the inference phases. My model is resnet-50 based tensorflow. who can help me solve this problem, thanks!

Comment: Original trained model can successfully complete the inference, but the converted model with tensorrt 3.0 are failed at inference phrase. Why the shape are [1,256,1,1], original should be [1,256]?

Comment: If the tensorrt are not supported the tf.matmul() function? if not, how can we do to solve the proble?